# Get Organization Profile by ID

Tags: organization-profile

I should find a organization profile by it's ID (GUID). The OrganizationProfileManager has methods to return profile by it's recordId(long) and search pattern(string). I looked for a solution to use search pattern but I have not find anything.

How can I get organization by it's ID? I do not like to use recursive method to go through all organizations.

thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe Reflectoring the `OrganizationProfileManager` class could give some insight into how SHarePoint itself uses that class. Using ILSpy you'll see that there is an

```
internal OrganizationProfile GetOrganizationProfile(Guid orgID)
```

method in the OrganizationProfileManager class.

Use Reflection to invoke it:

```
Type[] paramTypes = new Type[] { typeof(Guid) };
object[] paramInput = new object[] { orgId }; // your org id goes here

var manager = new OrganizationProfileManager(SPServiceContext.GetContext(SPcontext.Current.Site));
var methodInfo = typeof(OrganizationProfileManager).GetMethod("GetOrganizationProfile", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance, Type.DefaultBinder, paramTypes, null);
var profile = (OrganizationProfile)methodInfo.Invoke(manager, paramInput);
```